# Define regular polygon while iterating through a two-dimensional array.

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, polygons

I apologize ahead of time if this question was already answered - I may have stumbled across it but not realized it since I'm not entirely certain what all the symbols mean even after looking them up.

I'm attempting to iterate through a two-dimensional array (grid for a game) and check if a given coordinate is within the bounds of a polygon, in this case an octagon.

I'm just can't seem to figure out what the distance should be to check for.

As an example, for a circle I can just use the Pythagorean theorem to see if "c" is less than or equal to the given radius. If it is, then I change the value in my grid for that coordinate.

If it matters, this uses quadrant I in the Cartesian coordinates grid.

Please let me know if this is too vague and I will clarify - thanks in advance to anyone who even bothers to look at this!

Comment: How is the octagon defined?

Comment: you should be able to use the system of 8 inequalities based on line equations for the sides of the octagon

Comment: Can we assume that the polygon is convex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be a regular octagon in the $xy$-plane.

Given a point $Q$ in the $xy$-plane, the goal is to decide whether $Q$ is inside $S$, on $S$, or outside $S$.

Let $r$ be the distance from the center of the octagon to one of the vertices.

Preliminary transformations:

- $\;$Translate all points so that the center of the octagon is $(0,0)$.$\\[6pt]$

  $\;$Rotate all points about the origin so that some vertex has coordinates $(r,0)$.

Let the new coordinates of $Q$ be $(a,b)$.

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$L(x,y) = x + y(\sqrt{2}-1) - r$$
and let $v = L(a',b')$, where
\begin{align*}
a' &= \max(|a|,|b|)\\[4pt]
b' &= \min(|a|,|b|)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
The sign of $v$ is decisive:

- $\;$If $v<0$, then $Q$ is inside $S$.$\\[6pt]$

  $\;$If $v=0$, then $Q$ is on $S$.$\\[6pt]$

  $\;$If $v>0$, then $Q$ is outside $S$.

Done!

Comment: Thanks quasi! I didn't use this exact implementation, but I did get it working because of your assistance. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a (not necessarily convex) simple polygon in the $xy$-plane, with $n$ sides, such that the coordinates of the successive vertices 
$$P_1 = (x_1,y_1),\;P_2 = (x_2,y_2),\ldots,P_n = (x_n,y_n)$$
are known.

Suppose point $Q$ has known coordinates $Q=(a,b)$.

The goal is decide whether $Q$ is inside $S$, on $S$, or outside $S$.

First test to see if $Q$ is on $S$ . . .

If $Q$ is equal to one of the vertices $P_1,...,P_n$, then of course $Q$ is on $S$.

Next, assuming $Q$ is not one of the vertices, test to see if $Q$ is on an edge, strictly between the endpoints of the edge.

For convenience, define $P_{n+1}=P_1$.

Then $Q$ is on edge $P_iP_{i+1}$, strictly between $P_i$ and $P_{i+1}$ if and only if $Q = (1-t)P_i + tP_{i+1}$, for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < t < 1$.

This will hold if and only if the vector equation
$$(a,b) = (1-t)(x_i,y_i) + t(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})$$
has a solution with $0 < t < 1$.

Equivalently, equating corresponding coordinates, the condition is that for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < t < 1$, both of the equations
\begin{align*}
a &= (1-t)x_i + tx_{i+1}\\[4pt]
b &= (1-t)y_i + ty_{i+1}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
are satisfied.

So just solve the above system for $t$. If a solution exists, check to see if $0 < t < 1$.

Checking each edge in succession, you can determine whether or not $Q$ is on one of the edges, strictly between the endpoints.

Thus, you can determine whether or not $Q$ is on $S$.

Next assume $Q$ is not on $S$.

Choose some line $L$ through $Q$ which doesn't pass through any of the vertices of $S$, and is not parallel to any of the edges of $S$, and suppose $L$ has the parametric form
\begin{align*}
x  = a + ct\\[4pt]
y  = b + dt\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
for some $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, not both zero.

For $i=1,...n$, let $t_i$ be the value of $t$ for which the line $L$ intersects the (full) line through the vertices $P_i,P_{i+1}$, and let $Q_i$ be the corresponding intersection point.

Let $m$ be the number of points $Q_i$ for which

- $\;t_i > 0$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\;Q_i$ is on the edge $P_iP_{i+1}$, strictly between $P_i$ and $P_{i+1}$.

Note: Testing to see if $Q_i$ is on the edge $P_iP_{i+1}$, strictly between $P_i$ and $P_{i+1}$, can be done the same way as the analogous prior test for the point $Q$.

The parity of $m$ is decisive:

- $\;$If $m$ is even (possibly zero), then $Q$ is outside $S$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\;$If $m$ is odd, then $Q$ is inside $S$.

Done!

**Update:**

The procedure outlined above works for an arbitrary (not necessarily convex) simple polygon $S$.

For the case were $S$ is a regular octagon, it can be decided more easily$\,-\,$see my new answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer this for me - I really appreciate it.

That being said, I'm still unsure how to implement this even if the math is correct.

For instance, it looks like I need to define a list of vertices as the first step, but I'm not even sure how to do that.

I was also initially confuse by this part: t ∈ R

Upon looking it up though it appears this means an item (t) in a list of real numbers?

It would seem this is way more complicated than I thought it would be; if it's possible could you dumb this down even more? I am an art kid, math is hard.

Comment: How is your octagon defined? Is it a regular octagon?

Comment: Yes - and as I have tried some more approaches it seems there really is no way to do this without defining the points first as you described at the top (which I have nailed down at this point).

Comment: Is the octagon centered at the origin? Also, what is the radius of the circumscribed circle.

Comment: Yes, it is centered at the origin (whose coordinates cane be modified), though assuming 0,0 is fine. We can assume whatever number you'd like for the radius if it makes the explanation easier, though it will need to be mutable. I'm testing with a radius of 64.

Comment: @bit: For the case of a regular octagon, see my new answer.